# Laravel 5 can't login using Entrust

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3, entrust

I've been trying to get Entrust working with Laravel 5 following the instruction here https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

I've made all the changes as requested, added users and roles (I haven't added permissions as I won't need to check them...just roles), assigned roles to user and when I try to log in a user I get this error message

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\User given, called in
>   C:\www\procurement2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php
>   on line 385 and defined

I've no idea what this error means or how to fix it

Here is all the code changes

App/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'userlevel', 'buyer'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

App/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
       'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
       'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
       'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
       'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
       'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
       'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
       'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
       'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
       'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
   ];
```

App/config/app.php

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        ...

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,
];

'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        ...

        'Entrust'   => Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::class,

    ],
```

App/config/auth.php

```
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'users',
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App/User.php` should extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` instead of `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;`.